# Apache 2.4 + Codeigniter Urls working on HTTP but not on HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application with dynamic wildcard subdomains that are secured using ssl.
My issue is that only the home links are working with https i.e

https://sub1.site.com -- works

https://sub1.site.com/register -- gives a 404 error saying the file cannot be found on port 443

however 
sub1.site.com/register -- works

I have used this snippets to configure my site .

this is my config.php for the dynamic subdomains

```
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
 22 {
 23   $protocol = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https://' : 'http://');
 24   $config['base_url'] = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 25   $config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
 26 }
 27 else
 28 {
 29    $config['base_url'] = '';
 30 }
```

Then I have also used this to enable htaccess in apache2.conf

```
     AccessFileName .htaccess
154 
155 <Directory /var/www/>
156         Options  FollowSymLinks
157         AllowOverride All
158         Require all granted
159 </Directory>
```

and finally here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  2     RewriteEngine On
  3     RewriteBase /
  4     #this is to allow no indexes
  5     Options All +Indexes
  6         #www is not a subdomain 
  7         #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  8         #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  9 
 10     #Removes access to the system folder by users.
 11     #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
 12     #previously this would not have been possible.
 13     #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
 14     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 15     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
 16 
 17     #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
 18     #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
 19     #Submitted by: Fabdrol
 20     #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
 21     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
 22     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
 23 
 24     #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
 25     #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
 26     #request to index.php
 27     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 28     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 29     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 30 
 31 </IfModule>
 32 
 33 
 34 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 35     # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
 36     # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
 37     # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
 38 
 39     ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 40 </IfModule>
 41 AddType image/x-windows-bmp bmp
```

my virtual host configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available is as follows

```
1 NameVirtualHost *:80
  2 <VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
  3         SSLEngine On
  4         SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/wild/STAR_site_mobi.crt
  5         SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/wild/myserver.key
  6         SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/wild/site.ca-bundle
  7         
  8         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  9         DocumentRoot /var/www
 10         ServerName www.site.mobi
 11         ServerAlias site.mobi
 12         Redirect / https://www.site.mobi
 13         
 14         <Directory />
 15                 Options FollowSymLinks
 16                 AllowOverride ALL
 17         </Directory>
 18         <Directory /var/www/>
 19                 Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
 20                 AllowOverride ALL
 21                 Require all granted
 22         </Directory>
 23         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 24 
 25         # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 26         # alert, emerg.
 27         LogLevel warn
 28         
 29         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 30 
 31 </VirtualHost>
 32 <VirtualHost *:80>
 33         #SSLEngine On
 34         #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/wild/STAR_site_mobi.crt
 35         #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/wild/myserver.key
 36         #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/wild/STAR_site_mobi.ca-bundle
 37         
 38         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 39         DocumentRoot /var/www
 40         ServerName site.mobi
 41         ServerAlias *.site.mobi
 42         Redirect / https://*.site.mobi
 43         <Directory />
 44                 AllowOverride ALL
 45         </Directory>
 46 </VirtualHost>
 47 <VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
48         #SSLEngine On
 49         #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/wild/STAR_site_mobi.crt
 50         #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/wild/myserver.key
 51         #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/wild/STAR_site_mobi.ca-bundle
 52 
 53         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 54         DocumentRoot /var/www
 55         ServerName site.mobi
 56         ServerAlias *.site.mobi
 57         <Directory />
 58                 Options FollowSymLinks
 59                 AllowOverride ALL
 60         </Directory>
 61         <Directory /var/www/>
 62                 Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
 63                 AllowOverride ALL
 64                 Require all granted
 65 
 66         </Directory>
 67 
 68 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: http[s]://sub1.site.com/index.php/register does that work? with https in front

Comment: No that does not work :( I still get The requested URL /index.php/register was not found on this server.

Comment: first check that you can access a manually created file inside a folder... http[s]://sub1.site.com/myfolder/myfile.html if you can't then you didn't setup your ssl vhost correctly in apache and this isn't a codeigniter or htaccess problem

Comment: I created a test directory outside the application folder in the webfoot http[s]://sub1.site.com/test/test.html ... I can access that from the browser   let me add my vhost setup to the question @PK

Comment: ok. good your vhost is done correctly. now DELETE your .htaccess file and remove the base_url code in your config.php and try to access http[]://sub1.site.com/index.php/register and http[s]://sub1.site.com/index.php/register

Comment: if you can't access both url. try it with a brand new codeigniter. there's no reason it shouldn't work since your https and http is setup correctly. if it works, then add back your .htaccess. you should now be able to get both urls to work without the "/index.php" part in the url. if you are unsure if your .htaccess is working put some garbage text into your .htaccess file, you will get an error when loading your webpage if .htaccess is working.

Comment: @PK so after I deleted  the .htaccess and removed he code for the base_url (was I supposed to leave that empty or set it my base url?) http[s]://sub1.site.com/index.php/register gives me a 404, http[]://sub1.site.com/index.php/register gives me a 500 internal server error

Comment: keep the base_url there an empty. i think i you try with a fresh install of codeigniter.

Comment: I did also Ill try the fresh install try that in the meanwhile lets see if anything else turns up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vhost does not looks ok to me. ssl engine on should be in :443
And instead of reading .htaccess rules on the fly every page,include them once in /var/www/ Directory
Try somenting like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www
       ServerName www.site.mobi
       ServerAlias site.mobi
       Redirect permanent / https://site.mobi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
       #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www
       ServerName site.mobi
       ServerAlias *.site.mobi
       <Directory />
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride ALL
       </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           Require all granted
           Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
           RewriteEngine On

           # Instead of reading .htaccess rules on the fly every page,
           # Include them once, now, in this directory context
           AllowOverride None


          #Removes access to the system folder by users.
          #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
          #previously this would not have been possible.
          #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

          #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
          #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
          #Submitted by: Fabdrol
          #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

          #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
          #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
          #request to index.php
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
       </Directory>
       SSLEngine On
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/wild/STAR_site_mobi.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/wild/myserver.key
       SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/wild/site.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'include them once in /var/www/' I have tried this for my vhosts this doesn't seem to work link gets a 404  on https and 500 on http

Comment: I made a mistake, please check now. Also check if apache is listening to port 443.

Comment: I am still getting  404 when I try to access something like http[s]://sub1.site.com/register